# Google Place API not showing current result when I tried to search for AnimalClinics

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

Initially I tried

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.031959,%2072.895695&radius=10000&type=school&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCjQ03Ldxx9c55QmQ7ANGKRhEL*********s
```

this url and this showed right result

```
         "rating" : 3.4,
         "reference" : "ChIJSSUqsiDG5zsRyRBoSTT6WaA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "point_of_interest", "school", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 21,
         "vicinity" : "Janardhan Krishna Karmalkar Marg, Brindavan Colony, Chembur West, Mumbai"
      },
```

But when I tried to search for animal clinic it is showing some weird location.
My url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.031959,%2072.895695&radius=10000&type=AnimalClinics&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCjQ03Ldxx9c55QmQ7ANGKR********
```

result:

```
         "name" : "Nishraj Insurance Services",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
```

It is working fine only with School, Hospitals and Hotels location but I have to show the location of nearest Animal Clinics and Milk Dairy.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is working as intended because Animal Clinic is currently not supported in Place Types, you may visit the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) to see the current supported place types.

The possible place type for you is `veterinary_care`

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=19.031959,%2072.895695&radius=10000&type=veterinary_care&sensor=true&Key=YOUR_API_KEY

The result would be:

```
rating: 3.9,
reference: "ChIJVVVVlffO5zsR9rpcrHikEzs",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"veterinary_care",
"point_of_interest",
"establishment"
],
```